# remove NaN from output in html5

Tags: html, nan

I have a problem with a html5 output. Using autosum, when I remove a number, the output shows not a number in the textbox `NaN`.

How do I remove it?

```html
<form method="POST" oninput="result.value=parseInt(value1.value)+parseInt(value2.value)">
    <input type="number" id="value1" value="0"> +
    <input type="number" id="value2" value="0"> =
    <output name="result" for="value1 value2"></output>
</form>
```

Comment: (Obligatory [best to specify the `parseInt` `radix` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix) for now warning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a play on JSfiddle, is this what you're after? If the value for `parseInt` is not an int then it uses 0.

```html
<form method="POST" oninput="result.value=(parseInt(value1.value) || 0)+(parseInt(value2.value) || 0)">
  <input type="number" id="value1" value="0"> +
  <input type="number" id="value2" value="0"> =
  <output name="result" for="value1 value2"></output>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5acLpxqs/

Answer (score 0):

Use this  it fixes the issue

```
<form method="POST" oninput="result.value=parseInt(value1.value?value1.value:0)+parseInt(value2.value?value2.value:0)">
    <input type="number" id="value1" value="0"> +
    <input type="number" id="value2" value="0"> =
    <output name="result" for="value1 value2"></output>
</form>
```